# Instagram api comment pagination

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am using the Instagram api and fetching comments of media. I want to add pagination so that only 10 comments will come at a time. I have found nothing in Instagram api documentation to add limit for comments.
Is there any way to achieve that functionality?

Answer (score 2):

There is no pagination for comments, currently with API you can only get 120 latest comments.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe pagination is supported on all GET endpoints, though I haven't personally done this with comments. If you look at the general API Endpoints page in the documentation they say a count parameter is supported on all views where pagination is present, and then you just call next_url from the pagaination JSON object in the response to get the next set. They just don't mention this in each endpoint documentation page since it's the same for all of them.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

Answer (score 0):

With this library you can get all public comments from specific post: 
https://github.com/raiym/instagram-php-scraper

Or if PHP is not your language implement it by yourself according to this enpoints: https://github.com/raiym/instagram-php-scraper/blob/master/src/InstagramScraper/Endpoints.php

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on comments, and Instagram always return the last 150 comments.
I made a post and I commented 180 messages and the API just returns the last 150 comments